# Runtime Library Mismatch

Tags: visual-studio, dll, static, mfc

I'm building a static lib which I'm trying to link to a DLL. I'm running up against:

error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in blahblah.obj

But I have confirmed that I'm building both with **Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)**

So what does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: One of the libraries you are linking in links against an incompatible CRT and/or C++ Standard Library. Additional details at [Linker Tools Error LNK2038](https://msdn.microsoft.com//library/jj889284.aspx).

Comment: Phew! This is annoying! Does this mean that if I have to link a (third-party) LIB built in release, I can't build a debug version of my stuff? I can't find what is causing this - is there anyway to get any more info from the compiler?

Comment: You can use the [/VERBOSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx) command line option for the linker (`/VERBOSE:LIB`) to get additional information.

Comment: I found what was confusing me - an #ifdef in a header which turned off the _DEBUG symbol. Since I can't remember the last time I had to debug the C runtime, I decided to just build everything /MT and avoid the issue altogether...

Comment: Going for the /MT compiler options exchanges one issue for another. Now you have to deal with [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx). Undefining the `_DEBUG` symbol won't change the CRT you link against. That is still explicitly set through the compiler/linker options.

Comment: Yeah, typo...I'm build all my stuff with the /MD compiler option...no debug runtimes.